# Volume of a 3D simplex

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, simplex

I want to find the volume of the following simplex

$$B := \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} \mid x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0, x+y+z \leq 2 \}$$

I tried to do it by evaluating a double integral but I'm stuck with finding the right bound of integration. I tried the following:

$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2-z-x} (2-z-y) \, \mathrm d y \mathrm d x \mathrm d z$$

But I'm really unsure if this is the right approach. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or give me a link to some resources where I can learn more about this topic?

Comment: Is that a double integral? or a triple integral?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769545/volume-of-t-n-x-i-ge0x-1-cdotsx-n-le1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different methods of solution :

**First (analytical) method :**

First of all, in this kind of volume calculation,

- a) either you work with a triple integral as @StubbornAtom as done in his answer
- b) or (often preferable if it is possible) express your volume as the volume *over* a certain domain $D$ *under* a certain surface with equation $z=f(x,y)$, as a double integral :

$$\int\int_D f(x,y)dxdy$$

This is what we are going to do here with $f(x,y)=z=2-x-y$:

$$\int_{y=0}^{y=2}\left(\int_{x=0}^{x=2-y}(2-x-y)dx\right)dy$$

(please note the parentheses ; bounds of integration can be understood when looking at Fig. 1).

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The way the domain of integration $D$ (in plane $xOy$) is swept, for a given $y$, from $x=0$ to $x=2-y$.*

The integrand $(2-y)-x$ of the internal integral has an antiderivative (with respect to variable $x$) :
$$(2-y)x-\frac{x^2}{2} \ \text{to be taken between} \ x=0 \ \text{and} \  x=2-y$$

giving for the final value of the internal integral

$$\frac{(2-y)^2}{2}$$

It now remains to compute : $\int_{y=0}^2  \frac{(2-y)^2}{2}dy$ ; its value is

$$\frac{-(2-y)^3}{6} \ \text{to be taken between} \ y=0 \ \text{and} \ y=2$$

which finally gives the result $\frac43$

---

**Second (geometrical) method :**

This volume is a tetrahedron $OABC$ that can be considered as well as a three-sided pyramid (lying on one of its sides), with equilateral triangle $ABC$ (with sidelength $2\sqrt{2}$) as its base. The centroid of this base equilateral base has coordinates the mean of coordinates of $A,B,C$:

$$I=\tfrac13((2,0,0)+(0,2,0)+(0,0,2))=(\tfrac23,\tfrac23,\tfrac23).$$

The height of this pyramid is distance $h=OI=2/\sqrt{3}$.

It remains to apply the formula giving the volume of a pyramid knowing the area $S$ of its base and its height $h$ :

$$V=\tfrac13 \times S \times h = \tfrac13 \times 2 \sqrt{3} \times \tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\tfrac43.$$

as in the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help!

Answer (score 2):

One way is using a change of variables.

You can transform $(x,y,z)\to(u,v,w)$ such that $$u=x+y+z\,,\,uv=x+y\,,\,uvw=x$$

So that, $$x,y,z>0\,,\,x+y+z<2\implies 0<u<2\,,\,0<v,w<1$$

Absolute value of jacobian of  transformation is $$|J|=u^2v$$

Hence the volume is

\begin{align}
\iiint_B\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z =\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^2 u^2v\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w
\end{align}

Comment: Very exciting solution! Thank you very much.

Comment: Smart change of variables. How have you had the idea ? Did you know "increasing coordinates" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Increasing_coordinates ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. I remember having learnt this change of variables from a teacher of mine while finding the normalising constant of [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function) where the idea was to get the transformed variables independent of each other. I call it the [Dirichlet transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2619329/321264).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the different connections given in the referenced question (in particular to spherical $\to$ cartesian coordinates). Using this transform, you could maybe give a simpler answer to this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2573040 ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the geometric approach to finding the volume, an easier way is to visualise the pyramid whose height vector is along the $z$-axis from 0 to 2. Then the base is just a triangle with width 2 and length 2, so the volume is
$$V = \frac{1}{3}Ah = \frac{1}{3} \times (\frac{1}{2} \times 2 \times 2) \times 2 = \frac{4}{3} $$

Comment: The answer by Jean Marie has already mentioned this.

Comment: @JerryChang Jean Marie's answer uses a more complicated visualisation of the tetrahedron; for example, her value for $h$ is $2/\sqrt{3}$ instead of the simpler $h=2$ in my visualisation.

Comment: Oh sorry. I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

We start from
$$x\geq 0, y\ge 0, z\ge 0, x + y + z\le 2\implies 0\le z\le 2.$$
Now, fixing $z$:
$$x\geq 0, y\ge 0,x + y\le 2 - z\implies 0\le y\le 2 - z.$$
Finally, fixing $y$:
$$x\geq 0, x\le 2 - y - z\implies 0\le x\le 2 - y - z.$$